# BroadcastReceiver vs IntentService

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, intentservice

I see BroadcastReceiver and IntentService are used in [this](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/tree/master/LocationUpdatesPendingIntent/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/location/sample/locationupdatespendingintent) code to listen to location updates. This is a sample from google, so I assume there should be a good reason for it. IF you look at [LocationUpdatesBroadcastReceiver](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/blob/master/LocationUpdatesPendingIntent/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/location/sample/locationupdatespendingintent/LocationUpdatesBroadcastReceiver.java) and [LocationUpdatesIntentService](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/blob/master/LocationUpdatesPendingIntent/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/location/sample/locationupdatespendingintent/LocationUpdatesIntentService.java) , the contents are almost same. Is it because one work in background?

Comment: Did you read the notes in the comments on those two classes? https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/blob/master/LocationUpdatesPendingIntent/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/location/sample/locationupdatespendingintent/LocationUpdatesBroadcastReceiver.java#L32, https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/blob/master/LocationUpdatesPendingIntent/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/location/sample/locationupdatespendingintent/LocationUpdatesIntentService.java#L31

Comment: thanks Mike. To be honest, I read through the code and comments. I see BroadcastReceiver used widely in newer SDK and not sure why need to use IntentService. Also, how  they can coexist in system which supports both. Sorry, in the learning/struggling phase :-)

Comment: No worries. I was just trying to gauge exactly which point is causing the confusion. Anyhoo, both the `BroadcastReceiver` and `IntentService` essentially operate in the background, inasmuch as they don't really have UIs. The reason they use a `BroadcastReceiver ` in Oreo and up is that Oreo introduced limits on what can run in the background. Before Oreo, the Service would've worked just fine. Starting with Oreo, for apps targeting at least that version, the Service wouldn't be allowed to run in the background, but the Receiver broadcast is still allowed.

Comment: Since there's only a split-second's worth of work, they just do ahead and do it in the Receiver itself. I'm not sure why they show both methods, since the Receiver should work on all versions, but I would guess it's just for educational purposes. If you would need to do more work than what is demonstrated there, you probably would need to start a Service from the Receiver, so maybe they kept the Service as a general example.

Comment: thanks Mike. The below linked code lab explains it all. Wish I seen it first. Few nuggets. Here are strategies for targeting "O" and requesting location updates:
    Do not use PendingIntent.getService() when requesting location updates.
    Instead, use PendingIntent.getBroadcast() and register a BroadcastReceiver in the manifest.
They use one or the other based on OS version.

Comment: Oh, that's why they didn't just use a Receiver for all versions. They were explicitly demonstrating the new restrictions, and the necessary code changes. That makes sense, then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am making it point to point and not covering extra info, because there are many changes recently with the App background behavior and location updates in foreground and background.

In Android Oreo and above, when App goes to background, Intent Service cannot be started, whereas Broadcast receiver can be invoked.

Note: The code linked by you is part of android code-labs tutorials, further explanation of your code can be found in https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/background-location-updates-android-o